# Efficient XSLT Processor

Tags: xslt, converters, saxon

I was previously using the free version of Saxon 8.9 to convert XML based on some XSL. But the issue with that version was on large XML files of size 260 MB and above, Saxon gave "out of memory" exceptions. I got a free version of Saxon 9.2, but the issue is still the same. The machine has 2GB of RAM. Does anybody know a better version of Saxon or some other efficient converter that could solve the issue (but it has to be free)? If no free software is available, a purchasable converter could be suggested as well, but a product of Saxon at priority.

Comment: by pure curiosity, how can you build up 260Mb on a single XML document ? where is the data coming from ?

Comment: XML files can be greater than 260MB

Comment: SaxonEE 9.2.3 and later offers streaming extensions. It is very likely that in the nearest future Saxon will implement XSLT streaming as defined in the W3C XSLT 3.0 working draft. @Michael Kay is probably the best person to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried with an xml file of a bit over 300mb'

```
 -rw-r--r--    1 nicolasm Administ 311056011 Aug 12 15:27 test1.xml
```

And on the command line, boosted the memory settings a bit'

```
 java -Xmx1400m -jar saxon9-9.1.0.8.jar test1.xml test.xsl > out.xml
```

And the transformation went fine.

Note that

- I tested on Windows 32bits so cannot go over 1.5g of memory to create a java virtual machine.
- The XSL was kind of simple.

So, from there on, two questions:

- how complicated is your XSL. Memory usage for XSLT is largely dependent on what kind of instructions are used
- how much memory did you give to the JVM ?

Answer (score 1):

With huge documents, you usually want to avoid loading the whole document into memory at one time. Unfortunately XSLT isn't really designed to deal with this case (although it looks like XSLT 2.1 has some considerations for streaming, I'm not sure if there are any implementations yet).

Can you investigate the use of [Streaming Transformations for XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Transformations_for_XML) ?

Comment: Cool, didn't know this existed

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, XSLT has been designed such that it requires the whole XML document to be loaded in the memory. So, on average, the memory required to apply the XSL is usually twice or thrice the size of the input XML, or in worst case it may require memory up to 10 times the input XML size. Saxon 9.3 provides the functionality of streamed transformation of the XML. So, in that case, the memory consumed is consistent. But it requires changes in the XSL, and nodes processing one after another should be independent of each other. Streamed transformation of XML doesn't load the entire document in memory, and thus requires less memory and ideally can handle XML documents of any size.